# Can't install supervisord 3.1.3 on centos 5.2

Tags: elementtree, supervisord

I have tried to install supervisor on Centos 5.2 with easy_install but I receive errors as bellow:

```
Installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/supervisor-3.1.3-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for supervisor==3.1.3
Searching for elementtree
Reading http://cheeseshop.python.org/pypi/elementtree/
No local packages or download links found for elementtree
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('elementtree')
```

I try to download elementtree source & call python setup.py install also. But till errors.

Comment: This sounds like it's not a programming question

Answer (score 2):

I have follow below steps to install supervisor in my centOS.

Supervisor-3.1.3 requires three dependency :

- setuptools.
- meld3       (Download link: http://www.plope.com/software/meld3/ ).
- elementtree (Download Link: http://effbot.org/downloads#elementtree ).

Download and run 'sudo python setup.py install' command to set up each.

Then download supervisor-3.1.3 and install using sudo python setup.py install'.

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor 3 requires Python 2.6 ABI and therefore will not run on Centos 5